# MVC routing - specify id without action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to specify an id without having to include the index action.

Here is what I have tried:

```
routes.MapRoute("Upload", "Upload/{id}",new { controller = "Upload", action = "Index" });
```

This gives a 404 error. The url will be something like site.com/Upload/123

Comment: You can specify the route you expect to get with attribute instead of this, `[HttpRoute("upload/{id}")] before your method.

Comment: You should post code of the Upload controller. I suspect the Action Index without parameter id as a required parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to put the code before the Default route. MVC check routes from the any route after default won't work